# Gate count for Ring-LWE

Tags: encryption, aes, implementation, lwe

In one of my recent research, I need to compare the number of gates needed in Ring-LWE encryption to AES in the circuit model. For AES we can find some estimation like this [site](https://homes.esat.kuleuven.be/~nsmart/MPC/), but for Ring-LWE we can't find such an estimation.

- Could anyone give me an estimation?
- Is it safe to say the gate count for AES encryption is <1% of Ring-LWE under the same security parameters?

Thanks!

Comment: @kelalaka Actually this problem does not come from homomorphic encryption, so maybe the added tag is misleading.